# How to create a lightning component with an option to become a container for other components in App Builder? Is there any update?(Not Aura component)

Tags: lightning-web-components, app-builder

Last time that question was asked was 5 years ago. Is there any update of salesforce app-builder that let create a lightning component with the functionality to become a container? If not, do you know a way to provide other kind of hierarchy between components that you want to be included in each other (besides accordion component).
Thanks

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm Does this answer your question?

Comment: @AnkaiaBandi thank you, but not really, because Aura component is not suitable for my use. In general, I want to let some costume components to contain other costume components. I want to drug them from the list in the AppBuilder to a container that is inside them (such as if you let something to be drugged to an accordion but, not to an accordion only). Any kind of information/idea might help.

Answer (score 0):

Under https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/ you have couple of options to do that, but I would suggest one I like to use:
[image: lightning card under form-compound]

here how to get to that result:

```html
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-form--compound slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--fluid">
            <lightning-card></lightning-card>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
```